# optional chaining operator jest testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, chai

Newer to jest testing and reaching out to the community for direction. I need to write a jest test around the following block of code. The environment leverages jest, enzyme and chai. I have searched high and low for examples of optional chaining operator tests. Any examples or links anyone can provide to point me in the right direction.

```
<TableCell
   key={i}
   size={columnResizing?.columnWidths[column.id] || column.size}
/>
```

Comment: where this `columnResizing` is coming from? from props, some function call or separate constant? in general you just need to make this `columneResizing` be `undefined` but how to achieve that depends on where it comes from

Answer (score 5):

To enable optional-chaining, install it, like this:

```
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining --dev
```

After installing it, you need to ensure it's registered within your babel plugins section, like so:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll add this to my project.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a problem with optional chaining in jest + testing-library/react stack.

Test failed because of *"Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled"* can be resolved by adding

```
yarn add @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining --dev
```

Add plugins inside .babelrc to enable transformation:

```
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
   ]
```